# How to use OpenCV functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I've download the "OpenCV-2.4.9" and extracted it. Now I want to know how to connect it with Matlab, so that I can use OpenCV functions in Matlab. I'm using Matlab in which I've no "Computer Vision Toolbox", i.e. r2009b, and I've seen few functions of Opencv that can help me make a facial recognition software. That's why I want to connect OpenCV with Matlab and use OpenCV functions in a Matlab `.m` file.

Comment: try http://www.mathworks.de/discovery/matlab-opencv.html

Comment: I have used mexopencv http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/mexopencv/, but this is only suitable if you want to write mex code.

Comment: Unless you want to pay money, I think this is what you want: http://imageprocessingblog.com/matlab-bindings-for-opencv/ and http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/compiling-opencv-30-with-matlab-support.html

Comment: @B... i followed the links mentioned by you, but i'm encountering problems in every link, may be i'm doing something wrong in following the steps mentioned in the links. i found this link:

http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/mexopencv/

to be easiest among other ones, so i tried doing it alot of times.. now when i'm following the steps in this link's tutorial, i'm getting these errors.

Comment: @B... while using mexopencv.make, i got error

Error using mexopencv.make>pkg_config (line 184)
OpenCV include path not found: C:\opencv\include

then changed the path to C:\opencv\sources,i got error

??? Error using ==> make>pkg_config at 187
OpenCV library path not found:
C:\opencv\sources\x64\vc10\lib

Error in ==> make at 87
 [cv_cflags,cv_libs] = pkg_config(opts);

after i copied that x64 folder from C:\opencv\build to C:\opencv\sources,i'm getting this error

??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully

Error in ==> make at 106
        if ~opts.dryrun, eval(cmd); end

Comment: @B... i extracted my opencv2.4.9.0 to C:\ and after extraction, i'm getting two folders in it, build and sources.. if i use the default value of getargs fucntion mentioned in video tutorial of http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/mexopencv/, i.e.

 C:\opencv 

i get the line 184 error, 

if i set the getargs function value to C:\opencv\sources, then i get line 187 error, if then i copy x64 folder from build to sources, then i'm getting that this error:


??? Error using ==> mex at 208
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> make at 106
        if ~opts.dryrun, eval(cmd); end

Comment: just saying, opencv3.0 comes with matlab bindings similar to the python ones.